# How to make a big text in xaml more readable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a big text in xaml like:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
           Text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test" />
```

this makes a text that looks like this:

[image: Text with no breaks]

I would like to break it in xaml so it can be more readable in the screen while I program, but I don't want it to have a line break when displayed in the `TextBox`.

The problem is, when I type it in xaml like this:

```
<TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="Test Test Test Test 
                  Test Test Test Test 
                  Test Test Test Test 
                  Test Test Test Test 
                  Test Test Test Test 
                  Test Test Test Test 
                  Test Test Test Test 
                  Test Test Test" />
```

It's shown in the `TextBlock` like this:

[image: Text with breaks]

(this was it's displayed with the line break)

is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like it shouldn't be in the xaml at all.  Put it in a resource file.

Comment: Then I will have a long string in the resource file....the whole point of my question is avoiding to scroll back and forth to edit the text.

Comment: Then turn on word wrap in the text editor you're using to view/edit the resource file.

Comment: You can just carriage return it in the xaml, it's still going to load into the control as one long string unless you have xml:space=preserve on it which I don't see.

Comment: Well this could solve, but it's more like a "hack" on the text editor, if there is a way to signal this in xaml I would like to know

Comment: I don't see how either Servy's or my suggestion could ever be considered a "hack" in any regard?

Comment: @mFeinstein You consider using word wrap when editing text a hack?  I consider it an essential function that I only disable when absolutely necessary when using a text editor.  (With editing actual code being one of those necessary exceptional cases, but this isn't code, it's text *data*.)

Comment: @ChrisW. carrieage return do line break it in the TextBlock (if you mean just typing the "Enter" key).

Comment: Yep dude, just hit the enter key. ;)

Comment: @Servy I don't like to warp text because things change their position accordingly to the text's window size, and I have a visual memory, so this confuses me while I code....it's not a "hack" properly said, I just called it a "hack" to make my explanation short about this being an answer about the IDE and not the language (xaml) itself

Comment: @ChrisW. of course I tried this hahahaha it does break the text.

Comment: It shouldn't unless you've explicitly set whitespace to preserve....but maybe there's a difference between like `<TextBlock>Blah Blah Blah</TextBlock>` and `<TextBlock Text="Blah Blah Blah"/>` I'm forgetting since I always do the latter.

Comment: I tried both on VS2013 and it's the same

Comment: @mFeinstein So you want to have the text wrap (without explicitly adding in line breaks to it) so that you can see it all without scrolling, but you don't want the text to be wrapped because then it'll look different than how it's displayed when the program runs.  You've given conflicting requirements; the code can't both wrap and not wrap.  If you don't want it to wrap, then leave it as is; if you do, I've explained how you can do it.

Comment: Voting to close this one since the OP does not clearly state nor give any visual example of the expected outcome

Comment: @ChrisW. I messed something up in my tests here, you were right, I corrected the question, feel free to post <TextBlock>Blah Blah Blah</TextBlock> as an answer.

Comment: take a look at this if you need to do any further formatting withing the `<TextBlock>` [<TextBlock.Inlines>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx)

Comment: How to you get a TestTest out of that?

Comment: basically testing, copying pasting very quickly while coding and not paying attention hahaha I corrected the whole post, check the edits I made ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@mFeinstein,

If you have some long static text, putting it in Xaml is not stupid to me

```
    <TextBlock> 
        <Run>Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1 Test1</Run>
        <Run>Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2</Run>
        <LineBreak />
        <Run>Test3 Test3 Test3 Test3 Test3 Test3 Test3 Test3 Test3</Run>
    </TextBlock>
```

The text will appear as

Text1 ... Text1  Text2 ... Text2
Text3 ... Text3

Of course, it 's good both for reading the content in xaml, and editing in VS.
It is also very useful because you can provide different styles (underline,...) for each .

Moreover, even it is not useful in that example, you can bind to different data :
e.g. :

Regards, and thank you for your question mFeinstein

Comment: Thank you for your answer....I think in my case a simple "Enter" will do the trick....I was messing up `<TextBlock Text=""/>` with `<TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>`